# Struggling with background-image and <main>

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to use the background-image CSS property on the main. The image is being cut off. It doesn't look pretty. I've tried many different attempts and nothing is working. Also a scroll bar appears if I don't user overflow: hidden;

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
  <title>yfoment</title>
<!--scripts| CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\choco\Desktop\site\styles\main.css">
<!----->
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="margin-none">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="C:\Users\choco\Desktop\site\images\yfoment_logo.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">About us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-bg">

    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>

.main-bg {
 height: 85%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-image: url("C:/Users/choco/Desktop/site/images/hpbanner.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
}
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Literally tried all of the possible background-size values and similar properties.

Comment: Please check the preview of your added code. Add CSS and add the absolute URL of the background image(after upload it). It is not possible to understand where you are stuck.

Comment: How specifically do you want it to look? What have you tried and what goes wrong? At the moment, it looks like you have the background image on the `<div>` instead of the `<main>`.

Comment: This link will help you create a suitable runnable snippet to help us help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are experiencing is due to `background-size: cover`.

The [`background-size` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#values) `cover`
"Scales the image (while preserving its ratio) to the smallest possible size to fill the container (that is: both its height and width completely cover the container), leaving no empty space. If the proportions of the background differ from the element, the image is cropped either vertically or horizontally."

Additionally, I suspect that you desire for `main` to take up 85% of the height of the viewport. However, you declare this on a child element, therefore `div.main-bg` is 85% of `main` while `main` is auto-sized.

Background images can't be stretched without its intrinsic aspect ratio to fill the container like normal flow images can. If you would be okay with the outer edges of the background image getting cropped, add `background-position: center`.

```css
main {
  height: 85%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(//placeholder.pics/svg/500x300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li class="margin-none">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#" alt="logo icon">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
  <p>Whatever content this is</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

I tried this solution. It does not work. The image is cut off. If I scroll out to 33%, I can see it.

Maybe it is normal behaviour.

Comment: Do you think it could be the size of the image? It's 2701 x 2161

Comment: Nope. It seems that the <main> is always bigger. That seems to be my issue. 100% height doesn't fix it.

Comment: I think I have sussed it. The background image will always crop etc. I need to use an image. One that will not crop off important stuff. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. As I see, you are trying to give a height of 85% to the `div`, but the `main` has no height.

Try to give height to the `main` element first.

```
main {
    height: 100%; /* Or whatever your need is */
}
```

Also, remove `overflow: hidden` and see if it provides the results you want.

2. If you don't want the background image uncropped, there are two solutions.

The first one is, to add the `background-size: contain` property to the `div`

```
.main-bg {
    background-size: contain;
```

This will work but leave empty spaces if the size of the image and element aren't the same.

The second solution is ideal if you don't care about the absolute width of the `div`

```
.main-bg {
    height: 85%;
    background-image: url("#");
    background-size: cover;
    aspect-ratio: 16/9; /* Aspect ratio of the image */
}
```

Set the `aspect-ratio` of your background image to the element itself.

I hope this will work!

Comment: I tried this solution and had no joy. The background-image is being truncated. That is the part I cannot fix. It seems like that <main> is more significant than the viewport.

Comment: Do you think it could be the size of the image? It's 2701 x 2161

Comment: Nope. It seems that the <main> is always bigger. That seems to be my issue. 100% height doesn't fix it.

Comment: I think I have sussed it. The background image will always crop etc. I need to use an image. One that will not crop off important stuff. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @DevMark, background image never takes extra space it fits inside the element no matter how large the image is, neither it creates a horizontal or vertical scoll. You might need to brainstorm on the `main` and `div`. If you can provide any screenshot, I can better help you.

Comment: I try to post an image but it tells me it's too big. Any idea if StackOverflow allows external image links?

Comment: Yes, of course, it allows external links, until they are relevant or helpful to the question asked.

Comment: sorry for the slow reply. [imgur Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/hYDTzyl ) Here you can see a side scroll. This is what I want to get rid of.